# how to cout the longest permanent sequence (increasing or decreasing) in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, sequence

I have to make a program in C++ what can manage a sequence optionally with from 2 to 1000 element. At the end the program has to cout the longest increasing or decreasing sequence's numbers of element.

Examples:

**6;1;2;3;2;4;1; output: 3;** (because: 1;2;3 is the longest with 3 elements)

**6;4;3;1;5;2;1; output: 4;** (because: 6;4;3;1 is the longest with 4 elements)

I tired the following code and kind of working. The problem is that it cant give the longest one it gives the number of last sequence every time.

Unfortunately i cant find the bug or problem. Could anyone help please?

```
int counting = 1;
int counting_max = 0, counting_min = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if(block[i] < block[i+1]) {
            if(block[i]-block[i-1]>0) {
                counting++;
                    if(counting>counting_max) {
                    counting_max = counting;
                }}
                else {
                    counting = 1;
                }
            }

        if(block[i] > block[i+1]) {
            if(block[i]-block[i-1]<0) {
                counting++;
                    if(counting>counting_min) {
                    counting_min = counting;
                }}
                else {
                    counting = 1;
                }
            }
}
        if(counting_max >= counting_min) {
            cout<< counting_max;
        }
        else {
            cout<< counting_min;
        }


return 0;}
```

In my code I didn't share the first part because i guess it works properly.
The first is just a while and for function to call for the elements number and after the exact numbers in a block.
So in my code the block contains the numbers.

Comment: The bug can be found by giving it an example sequence of 1,3,7,5,2 -> If we are going from left to right then at 7 till now only 1st if( ) block was executed and counting = 3; in the next iteration 2nd if( ) block would be executed as 7>5 but still counting = 4 and you are assigning that to counting_min. To avoid all this confusion refer to my answer if it's of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have posted your outer loop creates an out-of-bounds access of the `block` array, since you're accessing `block[i+1]` in the loop. That's likely the reason that your code is producing correct answers in one direction and not in the other.

Beyond that there are some other problems you might come across with this approach:

- You probably don't need to keep track of two separate counters if in the end you take the largest. You could just keep track of the largest sequence regardless of if it increases or decreases.
- Since you test the relationships between three elements in the array to see if the sequence is increasing/decreasing, you will have to add extra logic to handle when the list has fewer than three elements.
- You need to be careful of when the same number repeats, as this probably does not count as increasing or decreasing.

Here's a revised version that covers these points:

```cpp
int counting = std::min(n, 1);
int counting_max = counting;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    if (
        block[i] < block[i + 1] &&
        (counting < 2 || block[i] > block[i - 1])
    ) {
        counting++;
    } else if (
        block[i] > block[i + 1] &&
        (counting < 2 || block[i] < block[i - 1])
    ) {
        counting++;
    } else if (block[i] == block[i + 1]) {
        counting = 1;
    } else {
        counting = 2;
    }

    if (counting > counting_max) {
        counting_max = counting;
    }
}

cout << counting_max << "\n";
```

Comment: For 5,7,5,7,5 It's showing 0, I just changed the block[ ] [link] (https://godbolt.org/z/IXip_E)

Comment: @Abdulkareem That's a very good point, and that's not the only problem with my suggested code. I was mistaken thinking that the solution was so close. I've updated my answer to highlight some potential issues.

Comment: So is the updated code on compiler explorer? The solution I provided works, but I wanted to see how we could solve it more efficiently

Comment: Yeah how does this look https://godbolt.org/z/ynmQ7i. It took longer than expected to product something that covered the edge cases like zero length, repeating numbers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternate code: counting_max is finding longest ascending sequence and counting_min is finding longest descending sequence(by decrementing its loop counter) and at the end, we compare them to find the ultimate longest(supposing we have n-1 elements, if not change it accordingly)

```
for (int i=1,j=n-2; i<n && j>=0; ++i,--j) {
    if (block[i] - block[i - 1]>0) {
        counting++;
        if (counting>counting_max)
        counting_max = counting;
    }
    else
    counting = 1;
    if (block[j] - block[j + 1]>0) {
        counting_back++;
        if (counting_back>counting_min)
        counting_min = counting_back;
    }
    else
    counting_back = 1;
    }

if (counting_max >= counting_min)
cout << counting_max;
else
cout << counting_min;
```